# ios different local notifications dayly

Tags: ios, iphone, uilocalnotification, localnotification

Im trying to make an app that would send a different notification each day for the time the user has the app. Im trying to make it such as that the user doesnt need to open the app (just open it once when downloaded) and keep receiving one notification each day with a different message.

Can this be done using a background job, or is there any good way to solve this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: when app launch first time . you can set max 64 `UILocalNotification` per app. so max 64 days you'll get notification. in between these days when user open app then get all remaining notification array using `[[UIApplication sharedApplication]scheduledLocalNotifications]` and then if array count is 30 then set more 34 notifications.

Comment: I had thought about that solution, but it needs the user to open the app at least once every two months. I wanted to know if there was a way to have this same behavior but without the user having to open the app. Do you think this is the only way to solve this?